# python script exits when a shell command(to terminate a different tool) is run from os.system()

Tags: python, shell, operating-system

I am running a shell command from within my python script using

os.system("some shell command")

This command essentially terminates a tool.
I need to check that this tool is terminated in my script.

But as soon as the tool is terminated the script is terminated too!

Comment: Is the script, by any chance, launched by that same tool?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the script, by any chance, launched by that same tool? If yes, you need to run os.setsid() to stop being dependent on it.

Comment: yes, it is highly likely that the script is launched by the same tool

Comment: This would be unfortunate if the script needs to interact with the terminal, as `setsid(2)` disassociates the process from the terminal. The shell command being executed would also need to be pretty specific -- either `0` for "all processes in my group" or `-pid` where the pid is the process group containing both this process _and_ the other process.

Comment: cant use os.setsid(), it gives error saying OSError: [Errno 1] Not owner

Answer (score 1):

Your script is probably terminating correctly. Try adding the following line after your last line of code to illustrate to you that it is done.

```
raw_input('Press any key to exit.')
```